# Iframe not to load automatically

Tags: iframe

Could you help me with one question I have. I have an iframe on my page that is loading automatically, but I wanted for it to have the option to have a button saying "Play" which would load the iframe and not having it loading automatically.

This is the code

```
<p><iframe src="https://demogamesfree.pragmaticplay.net/gs2c/openGame.do?lang=en&amp;cur=USD&amp;websiteUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fclienthub.pragmaticplay.com%2F&amp;gcpif=2273&amp;gameSymbol=vs15godsofwar&amp;jurisdiction=99&amp;lobbyUrl=https://clienthub.pragmaticplay.com/slots/game-library/ " width="100%" height="420px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" data-mce-fragment="1">&gt;</iframe></p>
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you!

I would like for the iframe not to load automatically and to have a button that the user would click on it to load the iframe.